# Deep Link into Android App using Google Assistant

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm developing a **DialogFlow Agent** which integrates with **Google Assistant** and uses **actions-on-google** Nodejs library to send back rich responses.

Is there a way to get Google Assistant to **deep link** into a part of your app using **actions-on-google** without user input (e.g clicking a Button), like how **App Actions** [built-in intents](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/intents) do when a user speaks.

So far i've seen: [OpenUrlAction](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.openurlaction.html), [LinkOutSuggestion](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.linkoutsuggestion.html) but that needs user input.

Apps like NetFlix and Spotify are able to deep link the user into the app, when a user issues a command via Google Assistant.
Do these use [actions-on-google](https://developers.google.com/assistant) or [app-actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview) ??

Comment: Look at [the android app linking docu](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) which describes how to link urls from other apps directly to your app, when you own the domain of the url

Comment: Correct. It's done via [App Actions](http://g.co/appactions).